# Selenium--driver.execute_script() wont work

Tags: javascript, html, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I execute a javascript with driver.execute_script but NOTHING occurs when I do--the system simply goes to the next python code line

Thoughts?
webscraping in webpage--using JavaScript in Console to datamine. The jScript works wonderfully when ***I*** put it to the webconsole

JavasCRIPT:

```
let email = '';
let contacts = document.querySelectorAll('div.contact-section');
for (let i = 0; i < contacts.length; i++) {
  if (contacts[i].getAttribute('automation-id') === 'contact-true-owner') {
    ele = contacts[i]
  }
}
let links = ele.querySelectorAll('address > a')
let last = links.length - 1;
email = links[last].innerText;
console.log(email);
```

Comment: Are you able to share a link to the website? What is the goal here and why do you need to use javascript instead of the webdriver element?

Comment: @NicLaforge appreciate u commenting. I cant show the website as it is an employer's site and u'd need access to see it.
Goals are: 1. Scrape for EMAIL addresses under  a specific title (it happens to be owner's email address here, no dox)
2. I had to work with JavaScript to find these emails BECAUSE in each page (I have 100's of 1000s to work with!) the exact Email I want may shift Xpath's or "titles", "headers" etc--so because of the inconsistencies in location, I had to work with this Script, which does work when I use it in the WebPage Console by itself (entering it in as a person :3) TY!

Comment: xPath is never a good idea IMO. You have not provided the command you executed from python, but I suspect there is a typo and you also need to return something (return instead of console). That being said, I still don't think you need javaScript for this. You may use `CSS_SELECTOR` to achieve the same goal. Something like `driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, '.contact-section[automation-id="automation-id"] address a')`

Comment: @NicLaforge the command I executed from python is: 
driver.execute_script('''
javascript for loop, identifies variables, names variables, console.log(...);
''')

I doubt there is a typo, or we'd see an error at the driver.execute_script( thing

Can I ask how to do a CSS selector? I have googled it but cannot sort it out--often these tutorials refer to things such as "TITLE" or "BODY" Or similar monikers which throw off my Xpath, so IDK why CSS would be any dif if they rely on div/div[3] etc

I am open to comments though and am simply trying to sort things out before deadlines :*-0

Comment: CSS_SELECTOR does not rely on `div`. You may include them but usually you will use specific classes/id/attributes. If you can join this room https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/240807/randomusername3 I might able to assist you.

Comment: @NicLaforge sup guy, the chatroom will not allow someone with < 20 points to joint. Agree, the Xpath's changed so I will try not to use them however now I have to figure out CSS's

Answer (score 2):

**Add return to script**

This script actually do nothing you could detect from python code.
The last line doesn't return anything..

Try to add the return statement:

```
...
email = links[last].innerText;
console.log(email);
return email
```

And also, it looks like the job you trying to do with `driver.execute_script` is just to locate the element and call `.innerText`. I gess it could be solved by providing the right xpath query (maybe css selector also OK, but xpath should work exactly).

I mean there is more strait-forward way to solve this issue, not just delegate it to *for loop* in `driver.execute_script`. But it's on your choice.

I'll be able to help you with xpath if you share the page-source. But it's optional.

**With xpath**

The idea is to perform 2 steps:

1 Find the element by xpath (other selector).

2 Pass it to executeScript as argument.

```
element = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[contains(@class, 'contact-section')][@automation-id='contact-true-owner']//address/a[last()]")

text = driver.execute_script('return arguments[0].innerText;', element)
```

Comment: @MaxDaroschanka, thanks, but the 'return email' function DID NOT return anything despite adding it into the forloop/script. 
the Xpath unfortunately change each time I see a different webpage (Have to scrape more than 2000 webpages!)

If somehow I could send keys to open the webpage console, enter the script (javascript) into said webconsole, then enter, then aggregate the output, that would fix my problem, but I cannot figure how to do that with selenium (simulating a man doing all that via keystrokes!) 

I 'would' source but I can not due to it being my employer's source code

Comment: Ok, it's strange that this works in web console but not in selenium. Regarding xpath - in your script you referencing tags, classes and attributes, so the xpath could be quite flexible to math all the data, you use for locate the element. I'll try just guess and add the xpath example without seeing you page source: `//div[contains(@class, 'contact-section')][@automation-id='contact-true-owner']//address/a[last()]`

You may check the xpath in chrome devtools, just open elements view and press ctrl+f, then insert the xpath and you'll see if it match something.

Comment: @MaxDaroschanka, thanks again. I will give you 2 example xpaths; they differ by 1 "div[#]" but are the same coveted data point I want for my scraper :)
/html/body/div[1]/div[1]/div/div/div[5]/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div[1]/div[5]/div[3]/div/div/div[3]/div[2]/div[2]/div/figure/figcaption/address/a[2]

and

/html/body/div[1]/div[1]/div/div/div[5]/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div[1]/div[5]/div[3]/div/div/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/div/figure/figcaption/address/a[2]


if you see they have 1 div difference, Y I can not rely on Xpaths--each page I visit may contain a slightly different Xpath

Comment: @randomUsername3 yes, I see, look at the above comment i've updated it with the example which may locate your element.

Also can you tell what selenium client do you use? webdriver.io or maybe selenium-webdriver? Just to be able to share come code example with this.

Comment: I see you're using python client, not js, ok.

Comment: @MaxDaroschanka, yes, I'm using a python IDE & selenium :)

IDK what selenium 'client' is but I see 'webdriver' in my python code, yes

Comment: Yes, client means webdriver in your tests :) so did you have a chance to try locating the target element using xpath?

Comment: the Xpath does not work because each webpage contains a variation within the webpage, so each page's Xpath may lead to a slightly different 'object' that I wouldn't want to take

Thanks